# Combine MySQL query with a row count query for optimization with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a working PHP script that selects the content with a join of a user table. Then I while loop the results.

However, I was wondering if it would be possible to instead of calling another query each loop, call it in the initial query? Basically merging them?

Code:

```
$content_result = mysql_query("
  SELECT content.id, content.type, content.title, content.url, users.username
  FROM content
  INNER JOIN users ON content.uploaderuid = users.id
  ORDER BY content.id DESC
  LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage
");

while($content_row = mysql_fetch_array($content_result)){
$contentid = $content_row['id'];
$result_num_votes = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votedcontentid = '$contentid' AND value = '1'"));
$num_votes = $result_num_votes['COUNT(*)'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(votedcontentid)as numbervotes,content.id, content.type, content.title, content.url, users.username 
FROM content 
INNER JOIN users ON content.uploaderuid = users.id 
JOIN votes ON votes.votedcontentid = content.id 
ORDER BY content.id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage
```

And here change it to

```
$num_votes = $result_num_votes['numbervotes'];
```